# What is the expected software maintenance pattern when switching Unity versions?

Tags: unity, software-engineering, support

What is the typical upkeep of a project made in Unity, specifically how often/how much the code needs to be updated/changed/added when a new Unity version  is released and/or when your currently used Unity version becomes deprecated?

I am not asking about a specific coding change. I am asking about the general pattern of upkeep needed whenever I need to switch Unity versions.

I want to avoid opinions. I know that it is impossible to predict the future. I am asking about objective facts about how Unity handles these updates.

Comment: [Campo Santo gave a GDC talk about making Firewatch in Unity](https://gdcvault.com/play/1023556/Level-Design-Workshop-Building-Firewatch), with memorable lines like "How I learned to --stop-- *keep* worrying --and love-- *but embrace* change" or "Holy shit we're running 5 frames a second faster and streaming doesn't crash anymore but all the cloth has disappeared". Unity's changed a fair bit since 2016, with a much better focus on stable versions and upgrade paths, so I expect your experience would be better, but it's so project-specific it would be hard to give general advice.

Comment: Is it safe to assume you're already up to speed on Unity LTS "Long Term Support" versions?

Comment: @DMGregory Thank you for the Firewatch video with those memorable lines. I'm familiar with the Unity LTS idea, though I am wondering about what happens when you have to move to the next LTS version.

Comment: @DMGregory Also, while I can give more information about genre (turn-based RPG and platformer), I assume it depends more on how someone programs the game rather than the genre itself.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that Firewatch was developed during the "puberty" age of Unity where they moved fast and broke a lot of things. The move from Unity 4 to 5 was especially problematic for many projects. But Unity Technologies learned from the backlash back then. Nowadays they do things a lot differently. Radical new and backwards-incompatible innovations (scriptable render pipelines, data-oriented tech stack, new input system...) are done in optional packages while the engine core is left relatively stable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*By design* updating from one Unity version to another *should* be a flawless process. Unity is pretty well-committed to maintaining backwards compatibility. This goes so far that when they discover essential design flaws, they often develop features from scratch and offer them as an optional package instead of fixing and enhancing the old system (Unity UI -> UIElements Package, IK System -> Animation Rigging Package etc.). That's because it's impossible to fix problematic behavior, because some people somewhere might rely on that behavior. Sometimes Unity deprecates scripting APIs, but there is a system in place to automatically change sourcecode to use the new APIs instead, and it even works occasionally.

However, that's not how it usually turns out in practice. The problem is that many game developers do things in Unity in ways they are not really supposed to be doing. They rely on undocumented behavior or use bugs as if they were features. And because game developers are really creative people, they love to build essential game mechanics which hinge on engine details. Details which the developers at Unity consider to be obscure edge-cases no *reasonable* game would ever rely on. Too bad that we game developers aren't reasonable people building reasonable software.

And in most cases we are not even aware that we are doing this. Heck, *I* have been doing this. I thought creating a "dark-light" by setting the intensity of a point-light to a negative value via a script was a cool trick. Until it stopped working a couple years ago, because it was actually not supposed to be possible to do that.

Are *you* doing things like that? Impossible to say. We don't know your project. And even if we *would* know it, our guess which edge-cases might behave slightly different in game-breaking ways in the future is as good as yours. We can not tell you "how often/how much the code needs to be updated/changed/added when a new Unity version is released" because that's very, very project-specific. Sometimes it just works. Sometimes the whole project is broken and you have no idea why. Or anything in between. It's simply impossible to predict if and how much problems upgrading to a new Unity version will cause.

(And by the way, in my experience, most problems are not with the script code no longer working, but rather with the behavior of the standard components now being slightly different).

So what general advise can I give for updating Unity during a project?

1. While you develop your project, try to follow best practices. Use it in the way the Unity developer expect you to use it, because those are the ways they are least likely to break in future updates. Unfortunately it's not always easy to find out how they want you to use it. Especially when you learn from 3rd party YouTubers who learned their stuff from other YouTubers. I always recommend to rely on the official sources, like the Unity manual and script reference and the Unity blog for cutting-edge features. When those official sources tell you "yes, here is the API, but you should probably use *other API*", then you should heed their warning.
2. Don't update your Unity project to a new version just because the update is there. Only update when you have a reason. Read the release notes, and then decide for yourself if it contains a bugfix for a problem *your project* is experiencing or if it contains a new feature that you need in *your project* to accomplish something that would otherwise be impossible or take much longer to do.
3. Do the update on a new branch of your version control system, so you can return to the main branch if it turns out the update causes problems. Unity says it's not possible to downgrade a project once upgraded. This is true, but only for people who don't use version control. If you have your whole project under version control, it's trivial to just return it to a previous commit. Seriously, if you are not using version control in this day and age, you are not doing software development. You are just fooling around. Yes, even for solo developers.
4. Test the project thoroughly. In a perfect world you would have an automated test suit you can run to make sure your game still works the way it worked before. Unfortunately in the real world most game developers don't take the time to create automated tests. Even though they are really useful for things like engine updates. So you probably need to test the game manually from start to finish.
5. Then you can merge the branch into the trunk of your version control.

Comment: And By the way: You might wonder why I did not  lose a word about the difference between LTS releases, regular releases and preview releases. The reason is that the "read the release notes, then decide if it's worth upgrading, then test properly" rule applies in *either* case. An LTS update for your branch is less likely to contain game-breaking changes, but is also less likely to contain anything that gives you a reason to update. But the chance of either happening is not zero either.

Comment: I think it might be worth mentioning that the use of packages for many of Unity's new features can also help with this: you can keep one package on an old version while upgrading another, so it's not an all-or-nothing commitment. You cna upgrade many aspects piecemeal, and version incompatibilities should often be confined to package boundaries.

Comment: Thank you, @Philipp for all of this helpful information and for your answer!

Comment: And thank you @DMGregory for this helpful strategy!

Comment: To clarify: Thank you, @Philipp for your very helpful answer and also this helpful comment!